# Post request body too large (string in parameter object too large)

Tags: c#, string, model-view-controller, post

I have an MVC method:

```
public void PushFile([FromBody]FileTransport fileData)
```

Class is:

```
public class FileTransport
    {
        public string fileData;
    }
```

In fileData I put `byte[]` from a file converted into a `string` (UTF-8), so the string can be large.

Problem is: if the string is **too** large (somewhere above 15000 characters) the `fileData` parameter is `null`. If the string is not that large, everything works fine and the parameter is as it should be.

How can I allow MVC to accept larger strings, or do I need to compress the string somehow beforehand?
EDIT:
Already tried:

```
<system.web.extensions>
<scripting>
  <webServices>
    <jsonSerialization maxJsonLength="2147483644"/>
  </webServices>
</scripting>
</system.web.extensions>
```

But does not work. Maybe because MVC uses JSON.NET instead of the normal JsonSerializer?

Answer (score 3):

Did you try to increase max length of the request?

```
<system.web>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="{REQUEST_LENGTH}"/>
<system.web>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Point is - you dont put the string into the URL. Simple like that. Add it as payload. URL's are ressource locators, not "Content carriers".

Answer (score 0):

I figured out it had nothing to do with content length. If seems like the Json does not encode properly with some characters on the sender's side, that's when MVC controller recieved null.